# Variable assignment resets internal array pointer

Tags: php, arrays

I have this PHP code:

```
$a=array(1, 2, 3);
var_dump(current($a));
each($a);
each($a);
each($a);
var_dump(current($a));
$b=$a;
var_dump(current($a));
```

The output is "int(1) bool(false) int(1)" but I expect "int(1) bool(false) bool(false)", because after three times `each` the internal pointer of `$a` should be after the end of the array and stay there.

But apparently the assignment `$b=$a` sets the pointer of `$a` back to the first element again. What is going on here?

(If I remove one `each`, the output is "int(1) int(3) int(3)" as expected.)

Comment: your question is bit unclear. sorry may be i am unable, but still can you put your expected outcome in a bit nicer way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php:

> Caution: Because assigning an array to another variable resets the original
>   array's pointer, our example above would cause an endless loop had we
>   assigned $fruit to another variable inside the loop.

Comment: Why does the assignment not reset the pointer if there are only two each instead of three?

Comment: That's a good question, and I guess the answer is in the question :) I guess it only resets when it got to the end. Open a bug-report to php so they fix clarify it in the documentation...

Comment: In PHP7 this does what you'd expect (return `1, false, false`) according to http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/.... In `5.6` it seems it doesn't...

Comment: Right... sounds like this was some sort of side effect which got fixed in PHP 7. Thank you both.

Comment: Well "fixed" is probably depending on point of view, I would say "changed the undocumented behavior", which of course will break some working code for people when upgrading php :)

Comment: @Gavriel It's not _undocumented_: the cited manual page clearly states it. Merely they didn't explain this choice further.

Comment: The fact that it (apparently) only resets the pointer when it's past the end is undocumented, also doesn't make any sense. That's why I think it was an unintended side effect.

Answer (score 1):

It's by design. This [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) states:

> Caution Because assigning an array to another variable resets the original array's pointer, our example above would cause an endless loop had we assigned $fruit to another variable inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is corrected in PHP 7.

```
$a=array(1, 2, 3);
var_dump(current($a)); // 1
each($a);
each($a);
each($a);
var_dump(current($a)); // false
$b=$a;
var_dump(current($a)); // php7-> false; php5.6 -> 1
```

The changes described on [php wiki](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/php7_foreach) page.